# Need to get Max/Min and all the rows in-between with a SELECT in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the Maximum and Minimum values and have those assigned as separate variables in php plus select all the other rows in between and have that as another variable then populate a dropdown list with the retrieved information.

```
SELECT z_depth AS z_depth FROM elements
UNION
SELECT MAX(z_depth) AS MAX FROM elements
UNION
SELECT MIN(z_depth) AS MIN FROM elements
```

The problem is that it is not returning `z_depth` AS `z_depth` and `MAX` as `MAX` etc, it only shows as `z_depth`. If somebody would not mind pointing out a solution or possibly an even better way to do it I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you are going to select all the rows why not just  order by `z_depth` then assign the variables in PHP? max is last and min is first (or vice versa depending on order type). `SELECT z_depth FROM elements order by z_depth asc`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL query:

```
SELECT z_depth
FROM elements
ORDER BY z_depth ASC
```

Read that into an array called `$results` and then do:

```
$min = min($results);
$max = max($results);
```

That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second column in the query which will identify the nature of the record ("max", "min", "other"):

```
SELECT z_depth AS z_depth,  'Other' AS Type FROM elements
UNION
SELECT MAX(z_depth) AS MAX, 'Max'   AS Type FROM elements
UNION
SELECT MIN(z_depth) AS MIN, 'Min'   AS Type FROM elements
```

The trouble with just doing a blind series of `UNION` queries as you had it is that you were ending up with a single column without knowing where any particular records might be.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like this

SELECT z_depth  FROM elements WHERE z_depth >=  ( SELECT MIN(z_depth) FROM elements ) && z_depth <=  ( SELECT MAX(z_depth) FROM elements ) ORDER BY z_depth ASC

Then you can always save the first and the last rows as min and max